# How to import from neighboring test modules when they are outside package source directory?

Tags: python, testing, import

Suppose I have a package structure like (as shown at [pytest.org](https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/goodpractices.html#tests-outside-application-code)):

```
src/
    mypkg/
        __init__.py
        app.py
        view.py
tests/
    test_app.py
    test_view.py
    ...
```

Now suppose `test_view` defines a `important_attr` that I would like to import from within `test_app`. How can I accomplish this? It seems like absolute imports don't work because `test_app` and `test_view` are not technically part of any package (so the absolute import can't be resolved) and relative imports are not allowed for the same reason (since relative imports don't seem to be allowed outside of packages when files are run as scripts?)

e.g.:

```
# test_view.py

important_attr = 42
```

```
# test_app.py

from .test_view import important_attr


def main():
    print(important_attr)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run `test_app.py` I get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

I could solve this by moving `tests` under `mypkg` directory, but I've seen the "separate tests dir from src dir" suggestion a number of times and I'm trying to understand how/if it can work for this use case. Maybe this is just a known downside of this strategy compared to having `tests` under `mypkg`?

adding `__init__.py` into `tests` directory didn't seem to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by changing the import to `from test_view import important_attr`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to tweak the value of the Python path, either by setting the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable before calling the Python interpreter, or by changing the `sys.path` array before trying to import the modules.

Something like this (I changed your example a bit):

./src/pkg/mod.py:

```
def go():
    print("Went")
```

./tests/t.py:

```
import os
import sys

# __file__ is the current file; take the parent directory of that, then append "src"
module_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "src")
sys.path.append(module_path)

from pkg.mod import go

go()
```